# Definition of sampling using delta or indicator function?

Tags: sampling, dirac-delta-impulse

I just came from a class where the professor showed a slide with the definition of sampling:

[image]

But I do not understand how we can multiply a signal $x(t)$ with the delta function $\delta(t)$, as the $\delta(t)$ is infinite at $x=0$. So this multiplication would amount to multiply a real-valued function with $\infty$ which is obviously not what is meant here. I think.

So would it make the formula formally correct if we would swap the $\delta(t)$ with the indicator function?

$$\mathbf{1}_0(x) =
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if } x = 0, \\
0 &\text{if } x \neq 0.
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that equation following "Conceptual scheme" is misleading.  the $\implies$ arrow is not an equal sign.  this is what is true:

$$\begin{align}
x(t) \times \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-nT_s) &= \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)\times\delta(t-nT_s) \\
&= \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x(nT_s)\times\delta(t-nT_s) \\
&= \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x[n]\times\delta(t-nT_s) \\
\end{align}$$

because we simply define $x[n] \triangleq x(nT_s)$.

the difference between the dirac delta and the indicator function is that one integrates to an area of 1 and the other integrates to an area of 0.

Comment: I can't see why you may exchange $x(t)$ for $x(nT_s)$.

Comment: because $\delta(t-nT_s) = 0$ for all $t \ne nT_s$.  the only time when $\delta(t-nT_s) \ne 0$ is when $t = nT_s$.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers, I would also like to point out that the "ideal" impulse sampler is usually considered to be followed by some filter of some kind, such as a [zero-order hold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-order_hold#Frequency-domain_model). The infinite-amplitude spikes are "averaged out" by convolving with the filter impulse response.

Also, even without any filtering after the impulse sampling, the spectrum of the sampled signal creates a mathematical model for the [aliased spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem#Aliasing) that is mathematically equivalent (up to a constant) with the periodic spectrum computed using the [discrete-time Fourier transform (DTFT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform#Definition).

Answer (score 2):

I think one important thing that you must understand is that a Dirac delta impulse is not an ordinary function that can be evaluated. So you do not multiply your signal with a value of $\infty$. What happens instead is that you weigh the individual shifted Dirac impulses with the corresponding values of the signal due to the following identity:

$$x(t)\delta(t-nT)=x(nT)\delta(t-nT)\tag{1}$$

which is true as long as $x(t)$ is continuous at $t=nT$.

Consequently, multiplying a signal with a Dirac impulse train results in a weighted impulse train, where the weights are the signal values at the sample instants. So what happens is that from a continuous signal $x(t)$ you only retain the sample values $x(nT)$, but you still have an expression that can be considered a continuous-time signal (in the sense that it can be integrated or convolved with another function).

Note that this is just a mathematical model. As pointed out in [Carlos Danger's answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/53143/4298), what usually happens is that this impulse train is filtered, i.e., you get

$$\left(\sum_nx(nT)\delta(t-nT)\right)\star h(t)\tag{2}$$

where $h(t)$ is the impulse response of the filter. Since $\delta(t-nT)\star h(t)=h(t-nT)$, Eq. $(2)$ equals

$$\sum_nx(nT)h(t-nT)\tag{3}$$

which is now an ordinary function which can be evaluated for any $t$.